# Procedure can't return large string response(~293 characters)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, nvarchar

Below is my stored procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PR_GETECOUNT  
( P_YEAR IN NUMBER
,P_RECORDSET OUT  NVARCHAR2
) AS 
l_r_count varchar2(400);
l_v_count varchar2(400);
l_e_count varchar2(400);
l_p_count varchar2(400);
l_s_count varchar2(400);
l_n_count varchar2(400);
l_e_count_upadted  NVARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN

l_r_count:=FN_GETECOUNT( 'R',P_YEAR);
l_v_count:=FN_GETECOUNT( 'V',P_YEAR);
l_e_count:=FN_GETECOUNT( 'E',P_YEAR);
l_p_count:=FN_GETECOUNT( 'P',P_YEAR);
l_s_count:=FN_GETECOUNT( 'S',P_YEAR);
l_n_count:=FN_GETECOUNT( 'N',P_YEAR);

--the values returned by FN_GETECOUNT are as below
l_r_count:='{"R":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}';
l_v_count:='{"V":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}';
l_e_count:='{"E":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}';
l_p_count:='{"P":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}';
l_s_count:='{"S":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}';
l_n_count:='{"N":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}';

--preparing response
l_e_count_upadted:='['||l_r_count||','||l_v_count||','||l_e_count||','||l_p_count||','||l_s_count||','||l_n_count||']' ;

  select l_e_count_upadted INTO P_RECORDSET FROM dual;
  

END PR_GETECOUNT;
```

**expected response**

```
  [{"R":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"V":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"E":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"P":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"S":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"N":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}]
```

actual response  is empty

**However if the length of response values is small then recordset returns correct response**
e.g

```
[{"R":[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]},{"V":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]},{"E":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"P":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"S":[4,7,2,4,12,2,3,3,9,0]},{"N":[17,3,23,4,44,55,5,2,1,0]}]
```

This seems to be limitation of max varchar2 size. please suggest how can it be solved.

Comment: why select into from dual? just assign p_recordset := to the concatenation. Also why are you concatenating varchar2 but returning it as nvarchar2? Also, unless this odd format is absolutely essential, it is not advisable to return a recordset via concatenated string. Oracle can return collections with proper datatypes and field names.

Comment: Your code has two syntax errors. `,` on the second line and the `l_e_count_upadted:=` line needs a trailing `;`.

Comment: When you call the procedure, how is the variable it's populating defined? e.g. if it's `pr_getecount(2022, somevariable);` maybe `somevariable` is too small.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure can be simplified to:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE PR_GETECOUNT(
  P_YEAR      IN  NUMBER
, P_RECORDSET OUT NVARCHAR2
) AS 
BEGIN
  P_RECORDSET := '['
              || FN_GETECOUNT( 'R',P_YEAR) || ','
              || FN_GETECOUNT( 'V',P_YEAR) || ','
              || FN_GETECOUNT( 'E',P_YEAR) || ','
              || FN_GETECOUNT( 'P',P_YEAR) || ','
              || FN_GETECOUNT( 'S',P_YEAR) || ','
              || FN_GETECOUNT( 'N',P_YEAR) || ']';
END PR_GETECOUNT;
/
```

Then assuming your other function is:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION FN_GETECOUNT(
  p_VALUE IN VARCHAR2,
  p_year  IN NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN '{"' || p_value || '":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}';
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_recordset NVARCHAR2(400);
BEGIN
  PR_GETECOUNT(42, p_recordset);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_recordset);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
[{"R":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"V":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"E":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"P":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"S":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]},{"N":[375,127,136,650,130,169,009,015,094,027]}]
```

*However, it is unclear why you use `NVARCHAR2` and not `VARCHAR2` like all the other variables.*

*It also seems wrong to be manually generating JSON when Oracle 12 and later supports generating JSON.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9jlceH0F)

Comment: thank you MTO, i am still getting **ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small** . i was trying  if changing VARCHAR2 to NVARCHAR2 will fix this issue, still no luck

Comment: @sanjeevRm The fiddle shows that the code provided works. You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77290124/edit) and include the error message that you are getting (as text, not images) and ensure that the line number for the error message does correspond to your procedure (and is not from whatever code is calling the procedure).

Comment: i found out that the API calling this stored procedure is getting the complete response.  however when i try to run the stored procedure from oracle sql developer client, the out is empty. so it seems to be issue with client.